# Show 'Total' after the end of each type of records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains two columns, ie. 
1. ClassName
2. Student Name

[image]

Comment: Note- In first table Total is not present, I have shown by mistake in image

Comment: Let [Pinal show you the way](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/24/sql-server-introduction-to-rollup-clause/) .

Comment: both pictures (current data, and dat you want) are the same, I guess you want to display total

Comment: Right Sir @KemalALGAZZAH

Comment: I posted a script, if it answers your question, please make it as your answer

Comment: Hello @Tab Alleman, how you can say that this is a  duplicate question. First, read the question carefully then make any decision.  Here I have no any column as type of INT.

Comment: To @Tab Alleman - By using any original question reply try to show the exact data that I want. Column name and type both should be same.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate only requires this small modification to answer your question:   instead of `sum(c.Score)` use `sum(1)`, since you desire a sum of 1 for each row in the rollup group.   Or even `COUNT(*)` as used by the answer you accepted.  The change isn't significant or novel enough to warrant a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[ROLLUP](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rollup/)** and add an union to your table

```
declare @mytable as table(classname varchar(100),studentname varchar(100))

insert into @mytable values
('10th','Hakim'),
('10th','Fathi'),
('9th','Saber'),
('9th','Wahid'),
('9th','Isamïl')

select * from 
(select classname,total=convert(varchar(100),count(1)) from @mytable
GROUP BY ROLLUP(classname)
union
select * from @mytable) v
where classname is not null
order by classname,isnumeric(total)
```

[image: Roollup sql server script]